# Should I hide the tab bar on iOS when I'm creating a new item?

Tags: iphone, ios, tabs

**Background**

I'm building an application with a tab bar at the bottom showing two different object types - for example, buildings and trucks.

Each of these tabs shows buildings and trucks in separate table views.

I want the user to be able to create a new building or a new truck.

I'm aware that it's common practice to hide the tab bar on a leaf view controller - but does this apply to the New Building/Truck screen too?

**Question**

When I show a New Building/Truck screen, should I hide the tab bar or show it?

Comment: I think I am looking at a very similar situation with an app design. I couldn't find much in the iOS design guidelines apart from tab bars should be consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I show a New Building/Truck screen, should I hide the tab bar or
>   show it?

You should hide it.

You'll find it common to completely push out the list view (including the tab bar) and show the new item-creation view. Then when the user taps on "Cancel" or "Done", they will be returned to the list + tab view.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at a very similar situation within an app. I couldn't find much in the iOS design guidelines apart from that tab bars should be consistent.

I think (and I'm no expert on iOS design) when you are performing actions such as adding/removing you can replace the tab bar with a tool bar that presents the required actions to the user. But would really need to see an example to see if it's actually going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for a complex action like that, you should probably use a modal view which will automatically hide the tab bar.

See also apple's Human interface guidelines for when to use modal views on iOS (and the equivalent for iPad): [IOS HUman Intface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW18%20Modal%20Views) see section on Modal Views.